# Accuracy of Tensorflow object detection Api

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am using Tensorflow object detection API models for my project. SSD MobileNet is the model I am working on.
I want to know, is there a way to find the accuracy of the model. Just accuracy, not mAP, because the model do find mAP but not accuracy.
So I wanted to know if someone has worked with Tensorflow object detection API models and know how to display Training data accuracy or Testing accuracy.

Answer (score 0):

- For SSD-MobileNet model you cannot get the training and test accuracy separately. To get the accuracy of the model you have to get the confusion matrix (True Positive(TP), False Positive(FP), True Negative(TN), False Negative(FN)).
- From the confusion matrix you can get the accuracy= TP+TN/TP+TN+FP+FN.
- To get the confusion matrix for the object detection model you have to find the Intersection over union(IoU) for the predictions.
- IoU is defined as the area of intersection between ground truth mask and predicted mask divided by the area of the union between the two.
- Based on the calculated IoU you have to define a threshold to get the True positive, False positive, True negative, False negative.

  For more details please refer to this [link](https://towardsdatascience.com/confusion-matrix-and-object-detection-f0cbcb634157). Thank You!